# Как избавиться от автоматической сортировки JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Перепробовала множество решений на этом ресурсе, ничего не помогает, данные приходят по api, менять что то в них у меня нет возможности.

Есть еще другой json, но очень большой и многоуровневый, с нем тоже самое.

Подскажите почему хром автоматически сортирует его?
Критически важно чтобы сортировка сохранялась.

```html
<script>
var dataUsers = {
  "3662": "Дмитрий Смирнов",
  "4356": "Олеся Лазарева",
  "2435": "Сергей Кузнецов",
  "2626": "Илья Брагин",
  "2624": "Артем Фокин",
  "3626": "Елена Борисова",
  "2352": "Анна Куликова",
  "2523": "Олег Трофимов"
};
console.log(dataUsers);
</script>
```

Comment: если вам сортировка нужно, то почему вы массив не используете?

Comment: @ThisMan, Как это сделать? Я получаю уже в виде json'a

Comment: ну вот пусть сервер формирует массив, а не объект

Comment: @ThisMan, этот api используют сотни людей, врядли они ради меня будут что то менять

Comment: Во-первых, у вас не JSON, а JS-объект. Во-вторых, в каждом первом справочнике указано, что порядок ключей в объекте не гарантируется. Как тут уже три раза написали, используйте массивы.

Answer (score 1):

В спецификации нет ни каких указаний, на то что ключи в объекте должны быть отсортированы ( иначе по какому правилу? ). Негласно правда, ключи все таки сортируются:

> Соглашение говорит, что если имя свойства – нечисловая строка, то такие ключи всегда перебираются в том же порядке, в каком присваивались. Так получилось по историческим причинам и изменить это сложно: поломается много готового кода.
>
> С другой стороны, если имя свойства – число или числовая строка, то
>   все современные браузеры сортируют такие свойства в целях внутренней
>   оптимизации.

[Подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

В вашем случае, вы можете сформировать свой массив ключей, который будет отсортирован по вашим принципам

```
const dataUsers = {
  "3662": "Дмитрий Смирнов",
  "4356": "Олеся Лазарева",
  "2435": "Сергей Кузнецов",
  "2626": "Илья Брагин",
  "2624": "Артем Фокин",
  "3626": "Елена Борисова",
  "2352": "Анна Куликова",
  "2523": "Олег Трофимов"
};

// сортируем по возрастанию
const sortedDataKeys = Object.keys(dataUsers)
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b));

const sortedDataUsers = sortedDataKeys
    .map(key => ({key, value: dataUsers[key]}));

console.log(sortedDataUsers);
```

Вся магия в этой строк строке

```
const sortedDataKeys = Object.keys(dataUsers)
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b));
```

Здесь происходит сортировка с помощью метода `sort`, можно передать любую функцию для сортировки
[Подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Жаль что нет решения, этот код тоже самое, сортирует по возрастанию. А как хотя бы сделать чтобы сортировка была по убыванию?

Comment: @OksanaDee ну вот строка `.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b));` вы сюда можете любую функция запихнуть, нужно убывание, тогда замените `>` на `<`